# SJFluidSegmentedControlBounce modification requires exclusive access error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Using SJFluidSegmentedControl Library having error in swift4. I tried look up their codes but still doesn't work

this is original codes from library

```
fileprivate func gradientColorForBounce(_ bounce:SJFluidSegmentedControlBounce) -> [UIColor] {
        var colors: [UIColor]?
        colors = dataSource?.segmentedControl?(self,gradientColorsForBounce: bounce)
        if colors == nil {
            colors = [gradientBounceColor]
        }
        if colors!.count == 1 {
            colors?.append((colors?.first)!)
        }
        return colors!
    }
```

and this one is new codes other ppl upload it "https://github.com/sasojadrovski/SJFluidSegmentedControl/pull/17/files"

```
fileprivate func gradientColorForBounce(_ bounce: SJFluidSegmentedControlBounce) -> [UIColor] {
        var colors: [UIColor]?
        colors = dataSource?.segmentedControl?(self, gradientColorsForBounce: bounce)
        var colorsCopy = colors
         if colors == nil {
            colorsCopy = [gradientBounceColor]
         } else if colors!.count == 1 {
            colorsCopy?.append((colors?.first)!)
        }
        return colorsCopy!
    }
```

i tried previous original code and new one but it keeps showing "Overlapping accesses to 'colors', but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable" or "Simultaneous accesses but modification requires exclusive access"

how to handle this problem? only occur in simulator. real device is working fine

Comment: In the second code which line gets the error message?

Comment: @matt i can build but when i run in simulator it shows "but modification requires exclusive access"

Comment: @matt i even tried "Build setting"->"exclusive access to memory" -> "unchecked" but still does not working

Comment: But which line???

Comment: @matt for the first code "colors?.append((colors?.first)!)"
 for the second one "colorsCopy?.append((colors?.first)!)"

Comment: @matt only problem happens in simulator. real device is working okay but still want to fix problem in simulator